# ExtJS function to toggle all checkboxes

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox

I have a simple list of HTML checkboxes, as follows :

```
   <input type="button" class="check" value="check all" onclick="foo()"/>

   <input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="1"/> Checkbox  1
   <input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="2"/> Checkbox  2
   <input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="3"/> Checkbox  3
```

On the click of the "Check All" button, I want to write a **ExtJS function** that selects all the checkboxes (and toggling it again deselects all the checkboxes) and returns the selected values in an array. I have done it using jQuery, but need to write it using ExtJS to which I am very new.

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.select('.chk').each(function(el) {
    el.dom.checked = true;
});
```

Comment: This solution only activates all `.chk` checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label for="check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="Toggle all" id="check" />
        Toggle All
    </label>
</div>
<div>
   <label for="chk1">
       <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="chk1" value="1" />
       Checkbox  1
    </label>
   <label for="chk2">
       <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="chk2" value="2" />
       Checkbox  2
    </label>
   <label for="chk1">
       <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="chk3" value="3" />
       Checkbox  3
    </label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('check').onclick = function() {
    var me = this;
    var out = [];
    Ext.select('.chk').each(function(el) {
        el.dom.checked = me.checked;
        if (me.checked) out.push(el.dom.value);
    });
    console.log(out);
};
```

See in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/GeoForce/Er2JF/1/

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution:

Markup:

```
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox" name="toggle" value="true"><br />
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="1"><br />
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="2"><br />
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="3">
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('toggle').onclick = function() {
  var isChecked = false;
  if (this.checked) isChecked = true;
  Ext.select('.chk').each(function(el) {
    el.dom.checked = isChecked;
  });    
};
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rayphi/ZeTvX/